# why keras-tuner .get_best_models() only returns untrained model?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, grid-search

Hi so using keras tuner to do gridsearchs on various hyperparameters.

using

```
tuner.results_summary(5)
```

returns hyperparameters and scores of the 5 best models.

We can see then that it is saving a record of the models.  But is it only saving the record of hypermeters and not models? When i call

```
model = tuner.get_best_models(num_models=1)[0]
```

the model returned is the untrained original default parameters used as a holding place for setting up the model going into the grid search. At least I can access the record of hyperparameters but is it possible to get the best trained model?

Comment: According to the [docs](https://keras.io/api/keras_tuner/tuners/base_tuner/#getbestmodels-method), it is returning the best trained model but it is recommended to retrain the model with the best hyperparameters for best performance.

Comment: ya that's where i'm stuck because if you print a layer its from the original model on set up before going into the gridsearch.   I'm testing and we the results from tuner.results_summary(5) as follows Hyperparameters:
dropout: 0.6
learning_rate: 0.1
inputN_values: 144
mid1Ns: 89
mid2Ns: 144
mid3Ns: 34
mid4Ns: 377
mid5Ns: 34
Score: 0.5542697906494141  but on print(best_models.layers) the neurens are for the before gridsearch setting if the neuran are different which won't change on training then I'm getting the wrong model, is it possible they will change during training?